# Create Nested If else in AWS Cloud Formation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am creating and attaching EC2 instance with Load Balancer in my CloudFormation template.
here instances in Load Balancer resource.

```
"Instances" : [
    "Fn::If": ["AttachLoadBalancerToServer1",
      {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [ "ServerStack1", "Outputs.Server1" ],
      },
      {
        "Fn::If": ["AttachLoadBalancerToServer2",
        {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [ "ServerStack2", "Outputs.Server1" ],
        },""  
      ]
      },""
    ]
],
```

I want to use this if else pattern in this:

```
if(AttachLoadBalancerToServer1){
"Instances" =  "Fn::GetAtt": [ "ServerStack1", "Outputs.Server1" ],
} 
else if(AttachLoadBalancerToServer2){
"Instances" =  "Fn::GetAtt": [ "ServerStack2", "Outputs.Server1" ],
}
else{
"Instances" =  "",
}
```

Any body can help me writing IF ELSEIF structure in this template? I am able to add one condition but not able to find how to use the second condition within one condition.

Thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I achieved the nested IF by adding the following structure in AWS CloudFormaiton template:

```
    "Instances" : [
        "Fn::If": ["AttachLoadBalancerToServer1",
          {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [ "ServerStack1", "Outputs.Server1" ],
          },
          {
            "Fn::If": ["AttachLoadBalancerToServer2",
            {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [ "ServerStack2", "Outputs.Server1" ],
            },{ "Ref" : "AWS::NoValue"}
          ]
          }
        ]
    ],
```

This worked well for me. I am posting answer because if someone stuck in future about the same problem my answer might help him.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a yaml example

```
 PlacementStrategies:
    !If 
    - IsPlacementStrategyConfigured
    - 
      !If 
      - IsPlacementStrategiesConfigured
      - 
        - Type: !Ref PlacementStrategyType
          Field: !Ref PlacementStrategyField
        - Type: !Ref PlacementStrategyType2
          Field: !Ref PlacementStrategyField2
      -
        - Type: !Ref PlacementStrategyType
          Field: !Ref PlacementStrategyField
    - !Ref AWS::NoValue
```

Comment: unbelievable. it worked. and I found your answer while listening SOAD.

Comment: I'm glad it can help anyone